# How can I get my iPod to only display synced music?

Tags: music, ipod

Our family has an iPod we use mainly for playing kids' music. I have synced only selected music to it. But the "Albums" list in Library shows a bunch of other music I've bought from Apple, which the kids would not enjoy.

Can I make it display only the music I sync to it?

Answer (score 1):

Haha, it didn't occur to me until I posted this to go look in "Settings" - I'm accustomed to Android where things like preferences are usually found from in-app menus.

Settings -> Music -> "Show All Purchases" and "Show Apple Music" can be toggled off, which solves this.